# Confidence interval for the mean - Normal distribution or Student's t-distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, mean, t-distribution

I have taken $N$ measurements $x_i$ of the time taken by a computer program to run a particular calculation, and would like to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the mean runtime. We can calculate the sample mean and standard deviation in the usual way:

$$
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N {x_i} \right); s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{N-1} }
$$

Now, as I understand it, if $N \ge 30$, we can appeal to the Central Limit Theorem and say that our sample mean $\bar{x}$ has come from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard error $\sigma / \sqrt{N}$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the population mean and standard deviation respectively. A 95% confidence interval for the mean runtime is therefore bounded by, for some $k_1, k_2$:

$$
\bar{x} \pm k_1 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}\ or\ \bar{x} \pm k_2 \frac{s}{\sqrt{N}}
$$

We can take $k_1$ from the normal distribution: $k_1 = Z_{0.975} = 1.96$. However, if we need to calculate a confidence interval without knowing $\sigma$, what value should we use for $k_2$?

1. According to the paper [Statistically Rigorous Java Performance Evaluation](https://dri.es/files/oopsla07-georges.pdf), we can also take $k_2$ from the normal distribution: $k_2 = Z_{0.975} = 1.96$. However, my understanding is that we should instead use Student's t-distribution with $N - 1$ degrees of freedom: for $N = 30$ this gives $k_2 = t_{(0.975, 29)} = 2.045$. Which of these is correct?
2. The same paper claims that the above method (using the t-distribution) is valid even for $N < 30$. Is this true, given that we cannot apply the Central Limit Theorem in this case? If not, is there anything we can say about a confidence interval for the population mean in the case $N < 30$?

Comment: Often computer running times to do a specific task are far from normally distributed. So my answer provides information on confidence intervals (CIs) based on non-normal data. // _Whenever_ the population variance is unknown, a CI for normal data is inherently a t CI (not a z CI) regardless of sample size. For large $n \ge 30$ (thus large degrees of freedom for t), and for a 95% CI _only,_ you can use 1.96 instead of a cut-off value from a t distribution as an approximation.

Comment: @BruceET - "Often computer running times to do a specific task are far from normally distributed." I am hopeful that when taking measurements, I can isolate my program from external system events that can cause outliers and/or a significant positive skew. I was hoping that this, coupled with the Central Limit Theorem, would mean that $N = 30$ measurements are sufficient to cause $\bar{x}$ to be approximately normal and a t-distribution CI to be reasonably accurate.

Comment: However, from your answer, it seems that $N = 30$ may not be "large enough" - is there a recommended methodology (perhaps including a test for normality?) to determine how many measurements I should take before calculating a t-distribution CI?

Answer (score 13):

**1. Normal data, variance known:** If you have observations $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ sampled at random from
a normal population with unknown mean $\mu$ and known standard deviation $\sigma,$ then a 95% confidence interval (CI) for $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 1.95 \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ *This is the only situation in which the z interval is exactly correct.*

**2. Nonnormal data, variance known:** If the population distribution is not normal and the sample is 'large enough', then $\bar X$ is approximately normal and the same formula provides an approximate 95% CI. The rule that $n \ge 30$ is 'large enough' is unreliable here. If the population distribution is heavy-tailed, then $\bar X$ may not have a distribution that is close to normal (even if $n \ge 30).$ The 'Central Limit Theorem', often provides
reasonable approximations for moderate values of $n,$ but it is a *limit* theorem,
with guaranteed results only as $n \rightarrow \infty.$

**3. Normal data, variance unknown.** If you have observations $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ sampled at random from
a normal population with unknown mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma,$ with  $\mu$ estimated by the sample mean $\bar X$ and $\sigma$ estimated by the sample standard deviation $S.$ Then a 95% confidence interval (CI) for $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm t^* S/\sqrt{n},$ where $S$ is the sample standard deviation and
where $t^*$ cuts probability $0.025$ from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom. *This is the only situation in which the t interval is exactly correct.*

Examples: If $n=10$, then $t^* = 2.262$
and if $n = 30,$ then $t^* = 2.045.$ (Computations from R below; you could also use a printed 't table'.)

```
qt(.975, 9);  qt(.975, 29)
[1] 2.262157  # for n = 10
[1] 2.04523   # for n = 30
```

Notice that 2.045 and 1.96 (from Part 1 above) both round to 2.0. If $n \ge 30$ then $t^*$ rounds to 2.0. That is the basis for
the 'rule of 30', often mindlessly parroted in other contexts where it is not relevant.

There is *no similar coincidental rounding* for CIs with confidence levels other than 95%. For example, in Part 1 above
a 99% CI for $\mu$ is obtained as $\bar X \pm 2.58 \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ However,
$t^*=2.76$ for $n = 30$ and $t^* = 2.65$ for $n = 70.$

```
qnorm(.995)
[1] 2.575829
qt(.995, 29)
[1] 2.756386
qt(.995, 69)
[1] 2.648977
```

**4. Nonnormal data, variance unknown:** Confidence intervals based on the t distribution (as in Part 3 above) are known to be 'robust' against moderate departures from normality.
(If $n$ is very small, there should be no far outliers or evidence of severe skewness.) Then, to a degree that is difficult to predict, a t CI may provide a useful CI for $\mu.$
By contrast, if the type of distribution is known, it may be possible
to find an exact form of CI.

For example, if $n = 30$ observations from a (distinctly nonnormal)
exponential distribution with unknown mean $\mu$ have $\bar X = 17.24,\,
S = 15.33,$ then the (approximate) 95% t CI is $(11.33, 23.15).$

```
t.test(x)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 5.9654, df = 29, p-value = 1.752e-06
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 11.32947 23.15118
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 17.24033
```

However,
$$\frac{\bar X}{\mu} \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=n,\text{rate}=n),$$
so that $$P(L \le \bar X/\mu < U) = P(\bar X/U < \mu < \bar X/L)=0.95$$
and an exact 95% CI for $\mu$ is $(\bar X/U,\, \bar X/L) = (12.42, 25.16).$

```
qgamma(c(.025,.975), 30, 30)
[1] 0.6746958 1.3882946
mean(x)/qgamma(c(.975,.025), 30, 30)
[1] 12.41835 25.55274
```

*Addendum on bootstrap CI:*  If data seem non-normal, but the actual population
distribution is unknown, then a 95% *nonparametric bootstrap CI* may be the best
choice. Suppose we have $n=20$ observations from an unknown distribution, with $\bar X$ = 13.54$ and values shown in the stripchart below.

[image]

The observations seem distinctly right-skewed and fail a Shapio-Wilk normality test with P-value 0.001. If we assume the data are exponential and use the method in Part 4, the 95% CI is $(9.13, 22.17),$ but we have no way to know whether the data are exponential.

Accordingly, we find a 95% nonparametric bootstrap
in order to approximate $L^*$ and $U^*$ such that
$P(L^* < D = \bar X/\mu < U^*) \approx 0.95.$ In the R code below
the suffixes `.re` indicate random 're-sampled' quantities based on
$B$ samples of size $n$ randomly chosen without replacement from among the
$n = 20$ observations. The resulting 95% CI is $(9.17, 22.71).$ [There are
many styles of bootstrap CIs. This one treats $\mu$ as if it is a scale
parameter. Other choices are possible.]

```
B = 10^5; a.obs = 13.54
d.re = replicate(B, mean(sample(x, 20, rep=T))/a.obs)
UL.re = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
a.obs/UL.re
    97.5%      2.5%
 9.172171 22.714980
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. In particular, it looks like the answers to my initial questions are:

Comment: 1. Since the population variance is unknown, the t-distribution value (e.g. $2.045$ for $N = 30$) is the correct value to use. However, for $N \ge 30$, the normal distribution value is a reasonable approximation.

Comment: 2. If we can assume that the data are normally distributed, it is valid to calculate a CI using the t-distribution even if $N < 30$. If they are not normally distributed, a t-distribution CI may or may not be useful. It's interesting that the "Statistically Rigorous Java Performance Evaluation" paper specifically says that, even for small $N$, "computing [t-distribution] confidence intervals does not require that the underlying data is [...] normally distributed".

Comment: I'll simplify further for normal data. If variance is known, use z; if variance is unknown, use t; ignore sample size. // For data of questionable normality, first ponder whether you know they're from some other distribution for which an exact test is known. If n small with no far outliers or obvious skewness or n large, maybe t is OK. Consider using rank-based test or bootstrap when in doubt. // 'Java' article mostly OK, but seems dated and derivative at points, would doubt it was refereed by a statistician.

Comment: Are there any good references that you can recommend that explain the ***nonnormal data, variance unknown*** case in more detail?  Such as how robust CI based on the t-distribution are to nonnormality, or ***when*** the nonparametric bootstrap is a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

First, $\sigma \over \sqrt{n}$ is not standard deviation, it is standard error. Second, *k* depends on the confidence level you are interested in and, as you said, can be taken either from a normal distribution or t-distribution. Third, the t-distribution is meant mainly for small sample sizes (**$n < 30$**) and for large sample sizes it doesn't matter whether you apply the **normal distribution** or **t-distribution** as the two approximate. Finally, if $\sigma$ is not known, better to go with the t-distribution using the sample standard deviation instead of $\sigma$.