# Confidence intervals for the mean using a t-distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, t-distribution

A summary of various cases is given in the first answer to the query:

[Confidence interval for the mean - Normal distribution or Student's t-distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358408/confidence-interval-for-the-mean-normal-distribution-or-students-t-distributi)

In the above, for case 3: **Normal data, variance unknown**, it is stated that one should use the t-distribution if mean and standard deviation of the population are *unknown*. However, the definition of the t-distribution, requires knowing the population mean (since t=($\bar{x}-\mu)/(S_x/\sqrt{N})$

Why is the t-distribution used to estimate the population mean (via confidence intervals) when the definition of the t-distribution requires that the population mean is *known* ?

Comment: I think you are confusing the $t$ distribution with Student's $t$ test

Comment: My question is: If you are using the t-distribution to find the confidence interval, the distribution requires knowing the population mean. In which case, why estimate the population mean in the first place ?

Comment: Pr($t_5 >= 2$) = 0.949. Look, no mean, no variance, only the degrees of freedom (5 in this case.

Comment: You are using $\bar{x} -(S_x/\sqrt{N})t$ to give a confidence interval for $\mu$ by choose suitable values of $t$

Answer (score 2):

The confidence interval is given by $$\bar{x} - c_{\alpha,n} \bar{\sigma},\hat{x} + c_{\alpha,n} \hat{\sigma}$$ where $c_{\alpha,n}$ is some constant that depends on the sample size $n$ and the confidence level $\alpha$.

The choice of this coefficient $c_{\alpha,n}$ will be based on the knowledge that the difference of $\bar{x}$ from the true mean $\mu$ divided by the estimate of the standard deviation will be following a t distribution.

So this thing $\bar{x} - c_{\alpha,n} \hat{\sigma},\bar{x} + c_{\alpha,n} \hat{\sigma}$ is the confidence interval. Your expression of $t$ is about the distribution of $\hat{x}$ *relative* to $\mu$.

---

The image below gives a geometric interpretation to the construction of the confidence interval (that image is from this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/425665) which is about a prediction interval for $x_{n+1}$ but it is similar in the reasoning with a confidence interval for $\mu$)

You see in the image the sample distribution of the estimate of the mean (x-axis) and the estimate of the standard deviation of the mean (y-axis). The diagonal lines show a region in which 95% of the observations will be. If for a given observation (depicted in red in the image) you would choose a confidence interval based on those same diagonal lines in reverse then for 95% of the observations you will construct a confidence interval that contains the mean.

This construction is independent of the true mean $\mu$. For a different mean $\mu$ this cloud of observations will be shifted to the left or right, but the principle of the construction of the interval will be the same. It is all *relative* to the true mean. The distribution for the *difference* of $\bar{x}-\mu$ is independent $\mu$.

[image: geometric example]

Comment: In order to tabulate the t-distribution, you would need to know $\mu$. In which case why bother to estimate it from the sample, via confidence intervals ?

Comment: I am referring to the value: $c_{\alpha,n}$ which is obtained from the t-distribution table. Constructing the table requires knowing $\mu$. Or am I mistaken ? Thanks.

Comment: @Frost in the expression that I give you only have $\bar{x}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ you do not need to know $\mu$. You only need to know how $\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sqrt{n}\hat{\sigma}}$ is distributed. This is, hypothetically speaking (e.g. you know that in about 68% of the time the mean will be $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ or more away from the true mean and in 95% of the time it will be $2\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ or more away).

Comment: So if you would know $\sigma$ and make an interval $\bar{x}\pm2\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ then you know that in 95% of the time the true mean will be inside that interval because you know that $\bar{x}$ will only be away more than 2 times $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ in 95% of the cases. If you do not know $\sigma$ but use $\hat{sigma}$ then you use the t-distribution instead. But the principle is the same, *'you do not need to know $\mu$*'. The distribution of the deviation between the mean of the sample and the true mean  $\bar{x}-\mu$ is independent of $\mu$.

Comment: The graphic at the end of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/425665/) may help as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any simple proof of your statement that "Distribution of $\bar{x}-\mu$ is independent of $\mu$" ? I understand that $\bar{x}$ is a random variable and $\mu$ is a constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116220/discussion-between-frost-and-sextus-empiricus).

Comment: @Frost would you agree that if $x$ is normal distributed with mean $\mu$ and deviation $\sigma$ then $x-\mu$ will be normal distributed with mean $0$ and deviation $\sigma$? So the sample distribution of an observation $x$ or $\bar{x}$ is dependent on $\mu$ but the distribution of the *difference* between the observation and the mean of the population ($x-\mu$ or $\bar{x}-\mu$) is not.

Comment: Yes, for a Normal distribution. However, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444537/will-adding-a-constant-to-a-random-variable-change-its-distribution!

Comment: @Frost but we are considering normal distributions not?